# Eclipse commands

Tags: java, eclipse

What is the difference between Ctrl + Shift + R and Ctrl + Shift + T?

Do we have a blog with all eclipse tips/shortcuts?

Comment: CTRL + SHIFT + L: Show Key Assist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ctrl-Shift-R: Find a *resource*, which can include XML files, Ant scripts etc.

Ctrl-Shift-T: Find a *type*, regardless of the filename. (This can be handy if you're looking for a nested type, or basically if you don't want to see anything other than types...)

For Eclipse shortcuts, there are *lots* of [Eclipse keyboard cheat sheets](http://www.google.com/search?q=eclipse+keyboard+cheat+sheet). From the search, I like [this PDF](http://eclipse-tools.sourceforge.net/EclipseEmacsKeybindings_3_1.pdf), [this shorter list](http://www.n0sl33p.org/dev/eclipse_keys.html), and [this list with more explanations](http://www.rossenstoyanchev.org/write/prog/eclipse/eclipse3.html).

Answer (score 3):

- Ctrl+shift+R is for Open Resource, it
  searches for all types of files in
  your projects.
- Ctrl+shift+T is for
  Open Type, it looks for Java classes
  and interfaces.

A great feature of the Open Type dialog is that you can search for say DataInputStream by typing DIS.

Answer (score 1):

- T : open a type (Java artifact)
- R : open any file (any resource)

Answer (score 1):

- Ctrl-Shift-T will find Java types including those imported in JAR files without source (e.g. Java standard API)
- Ctrl-Shift-R will only find Java types present as source code, but will also find other kinds of source files such as Text and XML.

Answer (score 1):

To see all key bindings look under Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys.

Answer (score 0):

Also, Ctrl+Shift+L will show you which keyboard shortcuts are active right *then*.

Comment: And pressing Ctrl+Shift+L again brings up the settings to modify them.

Answer (score 0):

Blatant advertising coming up:

If you like these two search options, you would love [nWire](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/). It is an Eclipse plugin for Java developers which provides, among other things, much stronger search. You get to search as you type for methods, fields, packages... practically everything you have in Java.

As for some more tips, I have written [the following article](http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/eclipse-34-hidden-treasures) in EclipseZone. I really suggest adding [EclipseZone](http://eclipse.dzone.com/) to your RSS feeds reading list. Lots of tips and good stuff there.